# understand std::unordered_map::find function, why not const?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

class A{};

int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World";

    std::unordered_map<A*, int> dic ;
    const A* a;
    auto it = dic.find(a);
    return 0;
}
```

this code complains "error: invalid conversion from ‘const A*’ to ‘std::unordered_map::key_type’ {aka ‘A*’} [-fpermissive]"

I can not understand it, the cpp refreence https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find
says I can find a  `const Key& key`, so I think `const A*`  could be used to find `A*`, but It does not work

Comment: `unordered_map` stores `A*` pointers, not `const A*` pointers. `const A*` doesn't mean "constant pointer to non-constant `A`", it means "non-constant pointer to constant `A*`. When `Key` is an `A*`, a `const Key&` actually means a constant-pointer to non-constant `A`, aka an `A* const`. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const)

Comment: It's also undefined behavior to use an uninitialized value like `a`, but your question would basically be the same if you did `const A* a = nullptr;` to initialize it.

Comment: Because of the way C++ grammar works, `const int*` is not a const pointer, but rather a pointer to const. What you want is `int* const`.

Comment: I think people are also missing the point here. `std::unordered_map` is capable of transparent comparisons as of C++20 and this code can be made to work just by adding appropriate hash and comparator arguments to the map type: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ver5YYjze. Yeah, it's a little more complicated than the default and it's a shame it has to be that way, but for ordinary types, it's sensible to not want a conversion to the key type.

Comment: What is the significance of the apparently-unused `using is_transparent = void;` line?

Comment: @NathanPierson So what do I need to do when I got const A* and need to find it in the map? I could not  change the key of the map to `const A*` because of the existing code

Comment: @NathanPierson, The method chosen to indicate that a comparator or hash supports the newer transparent capabilities while maintaining backward compatibility was to have said comparator or hash expose an `is_transparent` member that's a type. Which type doesn't matter, so making it an alias for `void` is pretty common. I'm pretty sure I've seen some code use `true_type` to match the name a bit more, but it's an awkward system in the first place. Functions such as `find` will individually check for the member's existence to know whether to allow non-key types.

Answer (score -4):

The **problem** is that is that when you wrote:

```
const A* a;
```

This means `a` is a *pointer to const `A`* which is different from a **const pointer** to `A`.

Also, from [std::unordered_map::find's documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find), it expects a `const Key&`. This means `find` takes the argument as a *reference to const `Key`*.

`Key` in your case is `A*`.

So in your case, this means that `find` expects the argument to be `A *const` and passed **by reference**.

But you're supplying/giving it an argument `a` which is `const A*`.
So there is **mismatch** in types of argument and parameter and hence the error.

Comment: A bunch of your explanation in this answer are true statements about `std::unordered_map` that don't actually have any relevance to why asker's code isn't behaving as they expect.

Comment: @NathanPierson I have added the correct explanation check it out.